# Mono Sql Driver issue

Tags: c#, sql, mono

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using C#.
Its working good in Windows.
the problem is when I run it in Ubuntu 16 using Mono It doesn't work and collation error happen. Here is the error:
[image]

here is my whole C# code :

```
private SqlConnection CreareConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=192.168.1.25;initial catalog=MesterCoin;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=147;");
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){throw ex;}
    }
    public List<Balance> GetUnAssigned()
    {
        var result = new List<Balance>();
        try
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Balance", CreareConnection());
            var rows = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rows.Read())
                result.Add(new Balance() { Id = int.Parse(rows["Id"].ToString()) , Address = rows["Address"].ToString() });
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        return result;
    }
```

I have installed mono using this link :
http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin
And  SQL server version is 2014.
The program works with Latin collations but not with Arabic And Persian.

Comment: Slightly confused in the title you say Sql Server and in the description you say Sql Server and MySQL. Are you having issue with SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @JohnMitchell sorry it was grammatical mistake.  It is Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Mono is a fantastic system but the developers can only implement so much at once, looking at their SQLClient they have come a long way but some of the features aren't quite feature parity with windows yet.

If this is a new project, and isn't super complex maybe have a look at .NET Core - it runs on Ubuntu now instead of having to run through mono.

Apart from that you may be stuck in a horrible situation of either keeping with windows, abandoning your current collation or looking at another database engine :\